# Custom single page for custom post type, wordpress

Tags: wordpress, posts

I've just figured out how to make custom post types and feed them out onto a page, I am wondering if I can change the single post pages for them?

Can I just set up a `single-news.php` for example? If so, how would that PHP file be formatted and how does WordPress know to use that `single-news.php file`? I'm just looking to have them spit out the full article.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After you created the CPT, do this for showing single posts of your CPT:

- Duplicate the `single.php` file in your template and rename it like
  `single-{post_type}.php` (eg. `single-movie.php`)
- Flush the permalinks from WordPress

You can get more details from [this post](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/08/27/showing-single-posts-of-a-custom-post-type-in-wordpress/)

- Now if you want to show a list of CPT you can use [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) with args:

  `$args = array(
  ...
  'post_type' => 'movie'
  )`

Comment: Just to add a note here. If you've created new CPTs and aren't seeing results with templates that are named correctly (including `single.php` or `single-whatever.php`) - FLUSH YOUR PERMALINKS. Just go to the permalinks page in WP-admin and hit 'save'. This solves the problem 9/10 times.

Answer (score 2):

```
Custom Post Type in wordpress. Basic four steps 

Step 1 : File Path location : theme/function.php in your theme

  Paste code in function.php (register custom post type )

  <?php

add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type_func' );
function custom_post_type_func() {
    //posttypename = services
$labels = array(
'name' => _x( 'Services', 'services' ),
'singular_name' => _x( 'services', 'services' ),
'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'services' ),
'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New services', 'services' ),
'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit services', 'services' ),
'new_item' => _x( 'New services', 'services' ),
'view_item' => _x( 'View services', 'services' ),
'search_items' => _x( 'Search services', 'services' ),
'not_found' => _x( 'No services found', 'services' ),
'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No services found in Trash', 'services' ),
'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent services:', 'services' ),
'menu_name' => _x( 'Services', 'services' ),
);
$args = array(
'labels' => $labels,
'hierarchical' => true,
'description' => 'Hi, this is my custom post type.',
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag', 'page-category' ),
'public' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'show_in_menu' => true,
'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'exclude_from_search' => false,
'has_archive' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'can_export' => true,
'rewrite' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post'
);
register_post_type( 'services', $args );
}
?>
```

Step 2: how can show wordpress custom post type in wordpress template page ?

```
  : you can show anywhere in template page like this :



<?php   $args = array( 'post_type' => 'services', 'posts_per_page' => 20 );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="services-items">
            <?php the_title(); 
        if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $post->post_title ) . '">';
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' );
        echo '</a>'; }

?>
            </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Step 3: Create new template for show single post like this

single-{custom post type name}.php
       or
single-services.php

Step 4: Paste code in single-services.php file

```
 <?php /* The loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="main-post-div">
                <div class="single-page-post-heading">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="content-here">
                <?php  the_content();  ?>
                </div>
                <div class="comment-section-here"
                <?php //comments_template(); ?>
                </div>
                </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

This is  custom post type example with single post page.

Answer (score 0):

for this purpose you can create the template file for your single-news.php page.
and get your post as you want by wordpress query.
for example your single-news.php page

```
<?php
//Template Name: Single News
?>

<?php
//get your content
$args = array('category' =>'9','posts_per_page'=> 3);
                        $myposts = get_posts( $args );
                        global $post;
                        foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?> 

//go with your content
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much. Forgive my oblviiousness, but is thee a way on the single post page (lets say for news in this example) to just spit out the title and content?